# why does npx degit sveltejs/template myproj fail with cannot find \Nodist\npmv\6.9.0\bin\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js

Tags: node.js, svelte, npx, nodist

Notice the npmv in the error.

cannot find module \Nodist\npmv\6.9.0\bin\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js

I installed nodist, opened a new myproj empty folder and am trying to follow the Svelte quickstart, node -v works in the terminal. NPX was not in the path so I corrected the windows environment variable PATH and restarted VSCode. |

The same error occurs when running in a cmd window in myproj dir.

What am I doing wrong?